# какие горячие клавиши используются в VS2013 для автоматической вставки #pragma region?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Пожалуйста, подскажите, какие горячие клавиши используются в VS2013 для автоматической вставки `#pragma region`? Что-то вроде этого: выделяешь текст, нажимаешь комбинацию клавиш и вводишь имя региона.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть Surround With, в контекстом меню редактора. Конкретный шорткат зависит от выбранной в студии темы:

Выделить текст, <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>#R</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, имя региона, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

или

Выделить текст, <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, имя региона, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.